# Filter JSON Obj

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting a JSON object from a `XMLHttpRequest` and am looking for a solution to filter bt `genre`. I also need a way to return all results (unfiltered) if no filterable parameter is passed.

**app.js (pseudo function)**

```
function filterObject(json, filterBy) {
  // filter through json
  // return item that matches filterBy
}
```

**data.json**

```
[{
  "date": {
    "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "month": "Oct"
  },
  "location": "Bristol",
  "genre": "rock"
}, {
  "date": {
    "dayOfWeek": "Cardiff",
    "dayOfMonth": 13,
    "month": "Oct"
  },
  "location": "Manchester",
  "genre": "jazz"
}]
```

Comment: There's already a `filter` function on Array instances that does what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` to filter your json on `genre` value.

```js
var json = [{"date": {"dayOfWeek": "Thursday","month": "Oct"},"location": "Bristol","genre": "rock"}, {"date": {"dayOfWeek": "Cardiff","dayOfMonth": 13,"month": "Oct"},"location": "Manchester", "genre": "jazz"}];

function filterObject(json, filterBy) {
  return filterBy ? json.filter(o => o.genre === filterBy) : json;
}

console.log(filterObject(json,'jazz'));

console.log(filterObject(json));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var json = [{
    "date": {
      "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
      "month": "Oct"
    },
    "location": "Bristol",
    "genre": "rock"
  }, {
    "date": {
      "dayOfWeek": "Cardiff",
      "dayOfMonth": 13,
      "month": "Oct"
    },
    "location": "Manchester",
    "genre": "jazz"
  }];

  function filterObject(json, filterBy) {
    if (filterBy !== undefined) {
      return json.filter(function(x) {
        return x.genre === filterBy;
      });
    } else {
      return json;
    }
  }
  var resultWithParameter = filterObject(json, "jazz");
  console.log(resultWithParameter);

  var resultWithoutParameter = filterObject(json);
  console.log(resultWithoutParameter);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filterBy as object with key and value properties to find any property you like (not only genre key).

```
   function filterObject(data, filterBy) {
    if(typeof filterBy === 'undefined') return data;
     return data.filter(function(item) {
      return item[filterBy.key] === filterBy.value;
     })
   }
```

Test:

```
  filterObject(arr, {key: 'genre', value: 'rock'}); // return rock band
  filterObject(arr, {key: 'genre', value: 'jazz'}); // jazz band
  filterObject(arr, {key: 'location', value: 'Bristol'}); // return band with location key
  filterObject(arr); // return initial array
```